# CSS Animation doesn't play

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, css-animations

I have been trying to do a simple animation in CSS. The app logo is supposed to move 200px to the right and then return, smoothly, to it's original position. To do this I have written this for the animations:

```
/* LOGO MAIN STYLE */
.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* ANIMATION FOR THE LOGO */
.App-logo {
  animation-fill-mode: forwards, none;
  animation-name: move-right, move-left;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s, 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite, infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes move-right {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
}

@keyframes move-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the first animation never actually plays, it just skips to the second.

Comment: can you provide a codepen ?

Comment: _"The app logo is supposed to move 200px to the right and then return, smoothly, to it's original position."_ - that doesn't need _two_ animations, you can do that with one - by using percentages instead of `from` and `to`. Set translate to 0 for 0% and 100% - and to -200px for 50%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* LOGO MAIN STYLE */
.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* ANIMATION FOR THE LOGO */
.App-logo {
  animation-name: move-right;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes move-right {
  0%{
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* LOGO MAIN STYLE */
.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* ANIMATION FOR THE LOGO */
.App-logo {
  animation-name: move-right;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes move-right {
  0%{
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).